# Private appointments in Exchange room's account listed as non-private

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

**Setup**

Service account: `tablet@domain` has full access to the calendars for `Room@domain`. It can view and create appointments in Room's calendar, both through Office365 and EWS (Managed) API.

If I (`user@domain`) book an appointment and register `Room` as the location, `Tablet` can view that appointment.

However, if I (as `user@domain`) create a **private** appointment and book it in `Room`, `Tablet` can **still** see the event (including subject). Moreover, `appointment.Sensitivity` is `Normal`, even when the original event was `Private, meaning that it is impossible for me to distinguish between them.

What gives? I don't think it is a Calendar Processing issue, as I didn't see any options in the `Set-CalendarProcessing` cmdlet which seemed relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is a calendar processing option that affects private meetings. By default if you book inviting a room, the private flag is stripped when it's added to the room. Set `RemovePrivateProperty` to false and it will retain the flag.

e.g. in PowerShell:

```bsh
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity "Room" -RemovePrivateProperty $False
```

Note however, all this does is preserve the private flag. You will still be able to read the subject and details, but sensitivity will show as private. It is up to the client to show or hide as appropriate. See also: https://www.grepular.com/Microsoft_Exchange_Private_Appointments_Arent_Private